# php file_put_contents character issue

Tags: php

i write a simple file editor

here are codes :

```
<?php
$file_path = "/home/user/file.php";
$file = file_get_contents($file_path);
print'  <form method="post">
    <textarea name="content" rows="20" cols="150">';
    echo $file;
    print'</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="save !">
    </form>';
if ( isset($_POST['save']) ) {


    $content = $_POST['content'];
    if ( file_exists($file_path) ) {
    echo "$file_path Updated"."<br>";
    file_put_contents($file_path,$content);


    }
    else {
    echo "The file $filenames does not exist";
    file_put_contents($file_path, ''); //Create empty file  
    }
}
```

in this file `$file` i have some html codes like

```
<div class="banner">
<a href="http://google.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
<img alt="" src="http://google.com/logo.png" ></a>
<br>
</div>
```

but when i save them via this script , it's be

```
<div class=\"banner\">
<a href=\"http://google.com/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">
<img alt=\"\" src=\"http://google.com/logo.png\" ></a>
<br>
</div>
```

it's works fine in localhost , i don't know what is a problem ,

Comment: You probably have [magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on... also if you put this code live at least one baby kitten will perish...

Answer (score 0):

`magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled.  Disable it in `php.ini` or do something like this in a global include:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('stripslashes', $_GET);
    $_COOKIE= array_map('stripslashes', $_COOKIE);
}
```

Comment: Add to that a check to see if the function `get_magic_quotes_gpc` actually exists as it's been removed in later version of PHP, but ideally you just disable it in `php.ini`

Comment: Maybe PHP 6 but not any version 5. In versions where `magic_quotes_gpc` has been deprecated `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` will always return `false`.

Comment: Aah my bad, PHP docs say: "Always returns FALSE because the magic quotes feature was removed from PHP.", I figured they'd removed the function entirely with the removal of magic quotes.